# How to wait Jenkins job for multiple git commit and then start the job

Tags: git, jenkins

Developers do frequents commits and due to this the automated testing job is executed each time after each commit (even for a smaller commit). Now, as our automation testing job takes lot of time, we would like to run the job only when at least few commits are added by the developer.

Agenda here is to make sure that our automation job is running on at least 3-4 git commits by the developers.

Example What is happening now : Developers commit something in the GIT repository, Jenkins job will poll for any commits and then start the job if found any change / commit.

Example What I want : Developers commit something in the GIT repository, Jenkins job will poll for any commits, now if Jenkins detect any changes then it should wait for 2nd commit within some time frame lets say 3 hrs, if Jenkins didn't find any more commits in the time frame of 3 hrs , it should start the job. But If Jenkins find any commits then it should wait for remaining time or start the execution.

Comment: Schedule a job every three hours and see how many commits you have at that time?

Comment: I don't think this will work because scheduling will run the job every 3 hrs regardless of commit and polling will also run the job immediately after each commit.

Comment: Can't you in the job determine if it is supposed to run or not? If commits happened in the last three hours?

Comment: I will try this, I will check if the plugin supports to poll for every 3 hours for changes and it there is a commit or series of commits then the job will run. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. You really should be looking into fixing the automated testing suite, or figuring out if it's possible for those tests to run in parallel.
2. I like DanielBarbarian's idea of polling every 3 hours for changes.
3. You could create some pipeline job which, on commit, clones / fetches the repo, and then validates if `num_commits % 3 == 0` or something before you run the tests.
4. It sounds like you're testing on development branches - instead, create a "test" branch or something, which developers can push batches of commits to, and test on that branch instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input, How and where can we validates if num_commits % 3 == 0, is there any plugin you know about, because if Jenkins see's a commit it will start the job and first step it will do it checkout the code, now if I check the number of commits and then decide to run the automated test then on the first instance the test will not run but job will execute just because the job is started and we cant hold the job. Next time it will do the same and so on..

Comment: Just to answer the points -- 1. My test are running in parallel, but very huge application, takes time.  2. I will try to poll for 3 hrs for any change.4. following the same process you suggested it just after every commit the job runs.